# Reading specific parts of a file

Tags: c#, linq

I have a file that is structured like:

```
[REG]
1
2
3

[LAP]
4
5
6
```

I just want to read the lines below the `[REG]` part, then i'll reverse the code when reading the `[LAP]` part but the following code is only giving me back `[REG]`

```
string[] commands = File.ReadLines(@"Engines\" + url_engine_code)
    .TakeWhile(x => x.TrimStart().StartsWith("[REG]"))
    .SkipWhile(x => x.TrimStart().StartsWith("[LAP]"))
    .ToArray();

foreach (var action in commands) 
{
    Helpers.ReturnMessage(action);
}
```

Am i missing something? my LINQ is not the greatest! thank you for any help, it is appreciated.

Comment: LINQ isn't really well suited for dealing with the sequential relationships between objects in an IEnumerable. It can be done (as as the answers here show), but it's kind of complicated and most likely involves reading the file multiple times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to reverse the `TakeWhile` test (I like to call that `SkipUntil`) and then use a normal `TakeWhile`:

```
var ans = File.ReadLines(@"Engines\" + url_engine_code)
             .SkipWhile(s => !s.TrimStart().StartsWith("[REG]")) // find line with [REG]
             .Skip(1) // skip line with [REG]
             .TakeWhile(s => !s.TrimStart().StartsWith("[LAP]"))
             .Where(s => s.Trim() != String.Empty)
             .ToList();
             
var ans2 = File.ReadLines(@"Engines\" + url_engine_code)
             .SkipWhile(s => !s.TrimStart().StartsWith("[LAP]")) // find line with [LAP]
             .Skip(1) // skip line with [LAP]
             .Where(s => s.Trim() != String.Empty)
             .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are saying to only read lines which start with `[REG]` -> `.TakeWhile(x => x.TrimStart().StartsWith("[REG]"))` the lines after `[REG]` but before `[LAP]` is what you want but none of those lines start with the text `[REG]`.
Try:

```
string[] commands = File.ReadLines(@"Engines\" + url_engine_code)
      .Skip(1) //Skip the first line [REG]
      .TakeWhile(x => !x.TrimStart().StartsWith("[LAP]") &&
        !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)) //Take while not the line which start with [LAP] and is not blank (empty)
      .ToArray();
```

In reverse, read until you get to `[LAP]`:

```
string[] commands = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\test.txt").Reverse()
                     .TakeWhile(x => !x.TrimStart().StartsWith("[LAP]"))
                     .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
                     .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation for TakeWhile: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.takewhile?view=net-5.0

I recommend always reading documentation from MSDN for .NET, it explains everything really well.

The TakeWhile method takes in an Enumerable and keeps returning elements while the condition specified is true. This line of code:

```
.TakeWhile(x => x.TrimStart().StartsWith("[REG]"))
```

will thus keep returning you strings as long as they start with [REG]. It will only give you the first line and then return.